# Plot lines for Travelling Salesman in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

Ok I have the following code and I want the lines to go from one point in the town's list to another point. But the plot command doesn't work properly, any ideas?

```
  clear;
  clc;

  numberOfTowns = input ("How many towns should be visited? ");  

  %Initalization of variables
  if ( !exist("numberOfTowns", "var") == 1 )
    numberOfTowns = 10; %Default value for numberOfTowns
  endif

  %Distances matrix
  distances = randi([0, 100], numberOfTowns, numberOfTowns); %initialize distances matrix
  distances (logical(eye(numberOfTowns))) = 0; %Make diagonal zeros

  %Towns List
  townsList = 1: numberOfTowns; %initialize townsList
  townsList = randperm(length(townsList)); % shuffle the vector

  %Points of towns
  townsPointsX = randi ([0, 100], 1, numberOfTowns);
  townsPointsY = randi ([0, 100], 1, numberOfTowns);

  plot (townsPointsX, townsPointsY, 'or');
  hold on

  for ( i = 1:(numberOfTowns - 1) )
    plot ( [ townsPointsX (townsList (i)) townsPointsX (townsList (i + 1)) ], [townsPointsY (townsList (i)) townsPointsY (townsList (i + 1))], 'g' );
  endfor
  hold off
endfunction
```

Comment: What does “doesn’t work properly” mean? Could you please describe the behavior you get, vs the behavior you expect?

Comment: It plots the intended lines and then it plots A LOT of random ones and I don't know why

Comment: Did you look at the contents of each variable? Did you run each of the plot statements one by one to see what they do? I recommend you use the debugger to learn how each line of your program behaves. https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Debugging.html#Debugging

Comment: I did check the variables, the output was correct. I finally managed to do it by storing the variables that I want in two new variables in a for loop and the plotting these variables